# Actionscript: get the name of a MovieClip by clicking its parent

Tags: actionscript, click, parent

I have a Sprite that contains many MovieClips: by adding an eventListener (Mouse.CLICK) to the container Sprite I want to get the name of the MovieClip clicked. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the "target" property? What scope do you get with it?

```
private function onMouseClick(ev:MouseEvent):void
{
    var mc:MovieClip = ev.target as MovieClip;
    trace(mc.name);
}
```

I'm on a netbook with no Flash environments so I can't verify this at the moment, but I think it should do the trick.